# stream exercises in scheme

Tags: stream, scheme

there is an answering as follows.
Write a Scheme procedure, called avg3 that takes a stream of numbers, and produces a number stream comprising the averages of triples of elements of the input stream. For example, the expression (avg2 s1to9) yields the stream 2, 5, 8 (s1to9 is the stream of numbers from 1 to 9).

Comment: What have you tried so far? you can't post a homework here without first showing some effort, the code you've written

Answer (score 0):

This is *clearly* a homework, it'd be a better idea if you tried to solve the problem by yourself. I'll give you some hints, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (avg2 stream)
  (if <???>            ; if the stream is null
      <???>            ; then return the null stream
      (stream-cons     ; else cons 
       (/ (+ <???>     ; add first element in stream
             <???>     ; with second
             <???>)    ; with third
          3)           ; and divide the addition by 3
       (avg2 <???>)))) ; advance the recursion, to the next 3 elements
```